# copy cell values

Tags: excel, vba

My data looks like

[image]

```
Sub CopyCols()
    Dim lngRow As Long, lngRow As Long

    lngRow = 1

    With ActiveSheet
            '.Cells(1, "E").Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 3).Copy .Cells(1, "A")
            .Cells(lngRow, "A").Value = .Cells(lngRow, "E").Value
            .Cells(lngRow, "B").Value = .Cells(lngRow, "F").Value
            .Cells(lngRow, "C").Value = .Cells(lngRow, "G").Value
            lngRow = lngRow + 1
        Next lngRow
    End With 'ActiveSheet
End Sub
```

I am trying to copy `E1:G16` to `A1:C16` but it is not working? Can anyone can help with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has error. You are not looping correctly. In fact I do not see a loop just a `Next` without `For`

Your code can be written as

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

'~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
Set ws = Sheet1

With ws
    For i = 1 To 16
        .Cells(i, "A").Value = .Cells(i, "E").Value
        .Cells(i, "B").Value = .Cells(i, "F").Value
        .Cells(i, "C").Value = .Cells(i, "G").Value
    Next i
End With
```

**However there is no need for a loop**. You can do it in one line of code

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

'~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
Set ws = Sheet1

With ws
    .Range("A1:C16").Value = .Range("E1:G16").Value
End With
```

Comment: Siddharth Rout

Sub pasteoneonecolumn()
Dim lngRow As Long, objCOMAddin As COMAddIn
lngRow = 1
With ActiveSheet
  For Each objCOMAddin In Application.COMAddIns
     .Cells(lngRow, "A").Value = .Cells(lngRow, "E").Value
     .Cells(lngRow, "B").Value = .Cells(lngRow, "F").Value
     .Cells(lngRow, "C").Value = .Cells(lngRow, "G").Value
     lngRow lngRow + 1
  Next objCOMAddin
End With
End Sub    
how does the code have the same function as ?

Comment: **1.** Please do not post code in comments. It is difficult to read them. If you want, you can update your question. **2.** Where did the `COMAddIn` AddIn come from? That is not part of your original question? If this is a separate quesiton then feel free to post another question.

Comment: I just checked your profile. Are you referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60334539/vba-excel-copy-paste-1-column-to-1-column?

Comment: Siddharth Rout, ok thanks finally I have the answer I'm looking for

Comment: Siddharth Rout
, how use 
 Dim lastRowCount As Integer
    totalRow = (Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    Dim DataRange As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim firstRowCount As Integer
    firstRowCount = 2
    While firstRowCount <= totalRow
, in vba that

Comment: LIke I said @IndraRoyalSilver: If this is a separate quesiton then feel free to post another question. You cannot keep asking new questions in comments :)